# Inner product with generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, inner-products, generating-functions

Let there be two real series $F=(f_0, f_1, f_2, \dots)$ and $G=(g_0, g_1, g_2, \dots)$ which satisfy $f(x)=\sum_n f_n x^n$ and $g(x)=\sum_n g_n x^n$, where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are given analytic functions. Is there a way to calculate the inner product $I=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f_i g_i$ using $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ without having to evaluate infinite sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be the radii of convergence of the the two power series $\sum_n f_n z^n$ and $\sum_n g_n z^n$. I have a positive answer when $R_1R_2>1$: choose $0<r_1<R_1$ and $0<r_2<R_2$ such that $r_1r_2=1$. Then
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(r_1e^{i\theta})g(r_2e^{-i\theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} f_k g_k.$$

Indeed, for each real number $\theta$ the series defining $f(r_1e^{i\theta})$ and $g(r_2e^{-i\theta})$ are absolutely convergent, so their Cauchy product, is absolutely convergent. But their Cauchy product is is $\sum_n w_n(\theta)$, where
$$w_n(\theta):= \sum_{k=0}^n f_k \times (r_1e^{i\theta})^k \times g_{n-k} \times (r_2e^{-i\theta})^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n f_k g_{n-k} r_1^k r_2^{n-k} e^{i(2k-n)\theta}.$$

For every $n \ge 0$ and every real number $\theta$,
$$|w_n(\theta)| \le \sum_{k=0}^n |f_k| |g_{n-k}| r_1^k r_2^{n-k}$$
Since
$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \Big(\sum_{k=0}^n |f_k| |g_{n-k}| r_1^k r_2^{n-k}\Big) = \Big(\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} |f_k| r_1^k\Big) \times \Big(\sum_{\ell=0}^{+\infty} |g_\ell| r_2^\ell\Big) < +\infty,$$
the series $\sum w_n(\theta)$ is normally convergent with regard to $\theta$, so
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} w_n(\theta) \Big) \mathrm{d}\theta = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \int_0^{2\pi} w_n(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta.$$
A direct computation shows that $\int_0^{2\pi} w_n(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta$ equals $2\pi f_{n/2}g_{n/2}$ if $n$ is even, and $0$ otherwise. The conclusion follows.

Comment: So what is the conclusion? How do you evaluate $I$ without having to evaluate an infinite sum over $n$?

Comment: I think you can relax the assumption into $R_1R_2>1$. If you choose positive numbers $r_1<R_1$ and $r_2<R_2$ such that $r_1r_2=1$, you compute $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(r_1e^{i\theta})g(r_2e^{-i\theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta.$$ and get the desired sum.

Comment: @bkocsis I generalised the result and put it in a form which will answer your question, I presume.